# Add users to create for a custom package in Buildroot

Tags: linux, buildroot

I'm adding a package in buildroot. Notably fcron-3.2.1. The documentation says to put this in the package makefile (fcron.mk) :

[**LIBFOO_USERS**](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#generic-package-reference)

```
Lists the users to create for this package, if it 
installs a program you want to run as a specific user (e.g. as a 
daemon, or as a cron-job). The syntax is similar in spirit to the 
makedevs one, and is described in the Chapter 24, Makeusers syntax 
documentation. This variable is optional.
```

So my fcron.mk file looks like this :

```
#############################################################
#
# fcron
#
#############################################################

FCRON_VERSION = 3.2.1
FCRON_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../fcron-3.2.1
FCRON_OVERRIDE_RSYNC = YES
FCRON_INSTALL_STAGING = YES
FCRON_INSTALL_TARGET = YES
FCRON_SITE_METHOD = local
FCRON_CONF_OPTS = --enable-shared
FCRON_SITE = www.nomad-digital.com

define FCRON_USERS
    fcron -1 fcron -1 * - - - Fcron daemon
endef

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

When I try to install in buildroot, I get the following error.

```
>>> fcron custom Installing to staging directory
Checking if group fcron exists ... no.
Would you like to add fcron in /etc/passwd with the following command ?
    groupadd fcron
If you use NYS, ldap, etc, you should add the group manually (say no here)
Please answer with 'y' or 'n' (default: 'y'): y
groupadd: Permission denied
groupadd cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
Group "fcron" does not exists : please create it or choose another groupname with configure script.
```

I have a feeling that I'm trying to create a user on the host machine not in my buildroot image, but even when I answer with 'n' above, it still does not pass and just says to please create a user. AM I createing the required user and group correctly in buildroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the *fcron* build system that tries to add the user and group to the host, since it apparently doesn't consider installation in a staging directory. You need to tell the *fcron* build system NOT to add the user and group during installation. If this is not immediately obvious from the *fcron* configuration options, you can look how distributions solve it, they will have the same problem. Possibly you will need to patch its `Makefile.am` and set `FCRON_AUTORECONF = YES` in `fcron.mk`.